# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY?

Tags: android, android-library

Basically I am developing an android app. Icreated a new library project and generated the aar file. Next in my main project I imported the aar file, added dependecy in my main project app module. Everything is fine till this point.

I wanted to use an activity instance of the aar library into my main project. So I added

```
<uses-library android:name="com.mylibray.project" android:required="true" />
```

in the main android manifest.

While installing it in android device/emulator getting  INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you please explain more? Which library it is and is it compatible with device/emulator you are trying?

Comment: solved the problem

Comment: Great!! What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using `Google APIS/Intel Atom x86` as CPU in the emulator, without Google APIS I always get that error you said. ;)